# Hibernate ignoring changes in schema.sql

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm developing an application with Spring Boot and hibernate, which connects to a postgres instance running in docker. When I first created my `schema.sql`, it looked like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE groups(
    group_id varchar(255) PRIMARY KEY,
    group_desc varchar(255),
    group_name varchar(255)
);
```

The table created successfully, however I soon realized 255 is too short for my purposes and changed my schema to the following:

```sql
CREATE TABLE groups(
    group_id text PRIMARY KEY,
    group_desc text,
    group_name text
);
```

However, the database keeps reverting to the original data types. I've tried dropping the table, however when the Spring app runs and it gets created again as `varchar(255)` instead of `text`. How do I force hibernate to use the updated schema?

I've tried changing the `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` property to `create` and `update`, and tried changing the fields to other datatypes, including other lengths of `varchar`. Nothing has worked so far. Even deleting `schema.sql` seemingly has no effect.

My `application.properties` looks like this:

```yaml
spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username=<redacted>
spring.datasource.password=<redacted>
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Text` datatype is not a `Varchar` but a `CLOB`.

Check your `Groups` class. I guess the `name` and `desc` attributes are `String` and the default related db type is then `VARCHAR(255)`. Thus, if you generate your schema from your entity, `String` always become `VARCHAR(255)`

If you want to use `Text`, your field should be annotated with `@Lob`

```java
public class Groups {
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "group_desc")
    private String desc

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "group_name")
    private String name
}
```

This being stated, I think you should change your java/db model because having a `Lob`/`Text` type as primary/foreign key frightens me a little (even if I never tried)

```sql
CREATE TABLE groups(
    group_id bigint PRIMARY KEY,
    group_code text NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    group_desc text,
    group_name text
);
```

```java
public class Groups {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "group_id")
    private Long id;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "group_code", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String code;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "group_desc")
    private String desc;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "group_name")
    private String name;
}
```

NB : I usually don't generate the schema from entities so I instead use the code below to map a db text field to entity attribute :

```java
    @Column(name = "group_desc", columnDefinition = "CLOB")
    private String desc;
```

But I am not sure if this is handled correctly to generate the schema

Comment: Using @Lob worked! So the schema.sql doesn't actually do anything?